# Should I create a COM or EXE for the app I'm executing as a trigger in MSMQ?

Tags: c#, triggers, msmq

I'm creating a trigger in MSMQ so that every time my web application adds something to my MSMQ queue an application gets executed.  My question is should I create a COM or EXE for the app I'm executing as a trigger in MSMQ?  I'm using C#.

Is there different ways to process these triggered responses?  if there are multiple items in the queue with triggers could all of the triggers go off at the same time?  Potentially could all the queued items start my EXE/COM multiple times? Or is there a way to only run one EXE/COM and hold the triggered items in a queue in my C# code? processing only one at a time.

Comment: Why would you even consider creating a COM component if an executable will do? How do you execute the application, through the trigger service? Why isn't it a consumer (e.g. Windows Service) that listens and processes?

Comment: it sounds like windows service is what I need.  It is something that runs constantly, so that I can create a queue in my code and allow for processing items one at a time.  Thanks CodeCaster!